# WM_COPYDATA и дочерние окна

Tags: c++, winapi, процесс

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять, гугль не отвечает: могут ли дочерние окна (`WS_CHILD`) получать сообщения `WM_COPYDATA`?

Паралельно, если не утруднит поясните за `CreateRemoteThread`, точнее за 4 и 5 аргумент. Нужно создавать такую функцию, имя должно быть именно такое?

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc( LPVOID lpParameter);
```

После, передать(впринципе через тот же `WM_COPYDATA`)в процесс, откуда буду запускать,и кинуть как аргумет в  `CreateRemoteThread`? Посмотрел определение типа 4-го аргумента, вроде всё сходиться

```
typedef DWORD (WINAPI *PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)(LPVOID lpThreadParameter);
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: `Нужно создавать такую функцию, имя должно быть именно такое?` сигнатура должна быть такой. А имя может быть какое Вам нравиться (и компилятор не против).  Более того, даже имена аргументов могут быть другие. Главное, что бы кол-во аргументов и их тип, а также тип возвращаемого значения совпадал (на самом деле должны типы совпадать бинарно).

Comment: @KoVadim, ага, с сигнатурой понятно, спасибо. Я вот ещё подумал: если я передам ссылку на функцию в другой процесс, то будет путаница, ведь другое адресное пространство, все дела. Пробовал, ничего не происходит, `GetLastError` выдаёт 6 - неправильный дескриптор. Но тут видимо речь идёт о дескрипторе процесса(1 аргумент), хотя вроде получал нормально. Подскажите в чём может быть дело?

Comment: "Не могу понять, ... могут ли дочерние окна (WS_CHILD) получать сообщения WM_COPYDATA?" -- почитайте [комментарии](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms649011(v=vs.85).aspx), особенно относительно ChangeWindowMessageFilter/Ex, быть может это причина Вашего вопроса.

Comment: @mega, не помогло

Comment: Разделите задачу, так проще всего искать ошибки.